# Using lodash throttle to throttle mouse events for some time wiring with automatic logout of user from our application

Tags: angularjs, typescript, lodash, throttling

I have a requirement in my project where I need to add the ability to logout a user after 30 minutes of inactivity. My project uses typescript and angular.

I can log the user out after 30 minutes of inactivity but since mouse move would cause an overkill of web app I wanted to use throttle/debounce.

Below code with throttle has a problem.

Suppose first click user event occurs at 7. This starts a timer for logout at 7:30.

Now since I have used throttle of 29 minutes, any click from (7-7:29) except the last click would be ignored. Suppose last click took place at 7:16. Now next throttle timer starts at 7:30 and since last event click was 7:16, code intelligently sets the timer to 7:46. Now suppose in throttle no 2 an event occurs at 7:42, now since this throttle would go on till 7:58, the timer cannot be reset till 7:59 and thus even if an event occurred at 7:42, user would get logged out at 7:46.

I am not sure if I have used throttle correctly. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
    constructor(public $element,public userService){
     this.timer=60000; //Just for checking purpose it is 1 minute
     this.setInactivityTimer();
     this.timeNewTimer=this.timer;

     this.myThrottleFunc = _.throttle(function(event){
      this.timeofLastEventInThrottle=event.timeStamp;
      this.timeNow=new Date().getTime();
      console.log("Event Triggered at"+ " "+(new
      Date(this.timeofLastEventInThrottle)));
      this.timeNewTimer =this.timer-(this.timeNow-      
       this.timeofLastEventInThrottle);
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutTimer);
       if(!this.hasFirstEventOccured)
        this.setFirstEventInThrottleTimer();
      else {
        this.setSubsequentEventsInThrottleTimer();
        //this.myThrottleFunc.cancel();
      }
    }.bind(this),this.timeNewTimer-1000);

    $element.on('click',this.myThrottleFunc);
   }

    public setInactivityTimer() {
    this.timeoutTimer=setTimeout(() => {
      this.logoutInactiveUser();
    },this.timer)
  }

    private setFirstEventInThrottleTimer() {
    console.log("Timer" + " "+ this.timer);
    this.timeoutTimer=setTimeout(() => {
      this.logoutInactiveUser();
    }, this.timer);
    this.hasFirstEventOccured=true;
  }

    private setSubsequentEventsInThrottleTimer () {
    console.log("New Timer" + " "+ this.timeNewTimer);
    this.timeNow=new Date().getTime();
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutTimer);
    this.timeoutTimer=setTimeout(() => {
      this.logoutInactiveUser();
    }, this.timeNewTimer);
   }

    public logoutInactiveUser(){
     console.log("Logout at" + " "+ (new Date()));
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a different, simpler approach to your problem. Check the following code:

```
constructor (public $element) {
    this.timer = 60000;

    this.debouncedLogout = _.debounce( this.logoutInactiveUser, this.timer );
    this.debouncedLogout();

    $element.on("click", this.debouncedLogout );
}

public logoutInactiveUser(){
    console.log("Logout at" + " "+ (new Date()));
}
```

You need `this.logoutInactiveUser` to be executed after `this.timer` milliseconds, if nothing else happened during this timeout. This makes debouncing that function the best solution:

1. You schedule the execution when your code initializes;
2. If no click happens during `this.timer` milliseconds, you'll be logged out;
3. If you make a click, the next execution will be scheduled to `this.timer` milliseconds from now.

Comment: I was a jerk trying to overthink the problem where debounce was lying there for me to use.I wish I could upvote you a gazillion times